# How to set relative path for a reverse proxy nextjs server

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have two servers A and B and both are hosted on AWS. `A` has a rule that says `/v2/` or `/v2` sends to `B`. That works fine. Server `B` is a NextJs application using nginx and express.

All routes are started with `/v2/` so `/v2/foo` shows a page. The page gives a response of `200` but not the assets. Server `B` has both private IP and public IP and going to either IP address for `B`: `<IP>/v2/foo`, the assets load fine. Going there from `A`: `<IP>/v2/foo`, assets does not load so I assume relative path issue?

I have found [this example](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/f2c2519159f49359cf90b6391772aa9a91e279d2/readme.md#dynamic-assetprefix) on how to set `setAssetPrefix`:

```js
// server.js

 const express = require('express')
const compression = require('compression');
const next = require('next')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare()
.then(() => {
  const server = express()
  // Not sure what this does
  app.setAssetPrefix('/v2') //??
  server.use(compression())
  server.use(bodyParser.json())
  server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

  server.get('/v2/foo', function(req, res) {
    app.render(req, res, '/v2/foo', {})
  })


  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res)
  })

  server.listen(3000, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log(`> Ready on ${process.env.HOST}`)
  })

})
.catch((ex) => {
  console.error(ex.stack)
  process.exit(1)
})
```

Using the both private and public ip address from server `B` works fine but when using server `A`'s url, the page hits but no styling. The homepage uses "css in js" and that works ok but not `/v2/foo` that uses `import ../../master.scss`

**next.config.js:**

```js
const sass = require('@zeit/next-sass')
const css = require('@zeit/next-css')
const withPlugins = require("next-compose-plugins")

const nextConfig = {
  webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/,
      use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
    });

    return config;
  }
}

//https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/issues/266#issuecomment-474721942
module.exports = withPlugins([
  [sass],
  [css, { cssModules: false, url: false }]
], nextConfig);
```

**nginx:**

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/v2/html/dist;
        #index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name <public_IP> <private_IP> <server_A_domain>;

        location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

Comment: This solves it for me: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/pull/2901#issuecomment-443966512

Answer (score 0):

try to pass all headers by adding `proxy_pass_request_headers      on;` to the `location` block

Comment: Thanks. Does not work. I need to be able to change the assets path/url/domain and that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom Express.js server:

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const next = require('next')

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
const dev = env !== 'production'
const app = next({
  dir: '.', // base directory where everything is, could move to src later
  dev,
})

const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

let server

app
  .prepare()
  .then(() => {
    server = express()

    // Set up the proxy.
    if (dev) {
      const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware')
      server.use(
        '/api',
        createProxyMiddleware({
          target: 'https://api.staging.gocrypto.com/',
          changeOrigin: true,
          cookieDomainRewrite: 'localhost',
          logLevel: 'debug',
        })
      )
    }

    // Default catch-all handler to allow Next.js to handle all other routes
    server.all('*', (req, res) => handle(req, res))

    server.listen(port, err => {
      if (err) {
        throw err
      }
      console.log(`> Ready on port ${port} [${env}]`)
    })
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('An error occurred, unable to start the server')
    console.log(err)
  })
```

Don't forget to rewrite your cookies (if you're working with sessions) to localhost with:

```
cookieDomainRewrite: 'localhost'
```

Then add a script to **package.json**:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "node devServer.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
  },
```